# parsing a unstructured JSON timeseries with Argonaut

Tags: scala, argonaut

a webservice returns unstructured JSON that looks like this:-

```
{
        "2018-04-09": {
            "1. open": "91.0400",
            "2. high": "93.1700",
            "3. low": "90.6200",
            "4. close": "90.7700",
            "5. volume": "31511758"
        },
        "2018-04-06": {
            "1. open": "91.4900",
            "2. high": "92.4600",
            "3. low": "89.4800",
            "4. close": "90.2300",
            "5. volume": "38026000"
        },
        "2018-04-05": {
            "1. open": "92.4350",
            "2. high": "93.0650",
            "3. low": "91.4000",
            "4. close": "92.3800",
            "5. volume": "29771881"
        }, ...
}
```

while I can parse the inner part using a Codec as it is regular even if it is ugly, even if I walk the cursor how can I walk down the unbound number of fields that represent the date if I don't know all the Date strings up front?

Is there a way to get all the siblings as JsonOjects and then extract the sibling name and its value?

Is this kind of thing un-parsable with argonaut?

Clues or some example code welcomed.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would parse it as a `Map[String,DailyStats]` where `DailyStats` is the inner part.

Comment: ok, how do you do that in Argonaut? the bit that i'm finding hard is how to get hold of an object while walking the Json that I can grab the fieldname and the Json of the value (which I can map to DailyStats) when I dont know ahead of time what the fieldname will be , it is a date string i wih it had been "date": "2018-04-23" then it would be easy as there are loads of examples of that in the doco